# Is there any alternatives to SharePoint 2013 for hosting Access 2013 Web Apps in house?

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, access, windows-server, cloud-business-apps

I am developing a solution for a small business which has the need to host all the data in-house and I was considering delivering it as an Access 2013 Web App. Since they don't want to have their database in the cloud, Office 365 is not an option.

The problem is that setting up a SharePoint 2013 server is [pretty much of an overkill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx) for what it will serve, so I was wondering if there are any alternatives to that for hosting an Access 2013 Web App.

I've read something about a [Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14117), supposed to be run on top of a Windows Server 2003, but I couldn't find any decisive information regarding if that would be able to host an Access 2013 Web App.

Please bear in mind that I am not familiar with Microsoft's technologies.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Access Services is not going to be a good choice for you. WSS 3.0 is out of mainstream support by Microsoft. As PirateEric mentioned Access Services is only available in SP Server ENTERPRISE, which is expensive. Without knowing your background it's hard to suggest anything. But I would look at Lightswitch.

Comment: Here is a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff796201.aspx

Comment: Why don't use Office 365 for hosting Access DB ? it's way cheaper then buying enterprise licenses for SP...

Answer (score 1):

You need an enterprise version of Sharepoint to run Access Services, either 2010 Enterprise or 2013 Enterprise. Apart from standing up an enterprise version, I don't know of a local technology that would allow you to use Access Services.

Answer (score 0):

WSS3/2007 and SharePoint 2010 aren't really being supported by Microsoft anymore and I doubt you can buy 3 anymore at all. What I think you may be angling towards is a custom ASP based website that utilizes ADO.NET to perform CRUD operations with your Access database. If all your users want to do is present the information and then be able to add/remove rows and that sort of thing, this would probably do the job for you. You would need to worry about all the theming-based and security stuff yourself, of course, but that's part of why SharePoint isn't a free product.

Answer (score 0):

@rodriguezalexa

As long as you don't require access to SharePoint Server or SQL, You could look for some provider who can provide Access Web Apps in hosted SharePoint environment. There are quite a few of them. For example, we have been providing Hosted SharePoint since SharePoint 2007 days to the latest SharePoint Server 2016. We are also a direct Tier 1 CSP.